# JIRA/FishEye Smart Commit Assigning Fix Versions

Tags: svn, jira, atlassian-fisheye, smart-commits

So we are using (or attempting to use) Smart Commits in Subversion with JIRA/Fisheye.  Successful smart commits generally follow the same syntax of the corresponding JIRA action such as #comment, #developer-accepts, #close, #resolve, etc.  The command #start-work also works as a smart commit; however, in our instance of JIRA- you cannot start work on a ticket without selecting a Fix Version for that ticket.  I am wondering if there is a command to add after #start-work so JIRA can assign the fix version to that ticket and accept the smart commit?

The error message we get from Fisheye is "FishEye was unable to execute the transition "Start-Work" on the issue XX-123 because JIRA responded with the following error: fixVersions: Fix Version/s is required.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there is no smart commit command to allow you to automatically add a fix-version to a JIRA issue. Feel free to raise a feature request for that though!